# Linux as router - How can I determine which route to use (depends on different source addresses)

Tags: linux, routing

I have a Linux server and I used it as a router, which has two network interfaces.

I use eth0(10.76.8.60/24, 10.76.8.50/24, router: 10.76.8.1) to connect to the network, and eth1(192.168.1.1/24) connect to the LAN switch. I use SNAT to forward the packets from eth1 to eth0.

The problem is that I want to forward the packet from a specified client (such as 192.168.1.8, SNAT to 10.76.8.60) to 10.76.8.111 (not the default gateway : 10.76.8.1, SNAT to 10.76.8.50), but other clients' packets still be forwarded to the default gateway.

I tried to solve the problem using ip route table, but failed:

```
ip route flush table test
ip route add default via 10.76.8.111 src 10.76.8.60 table test
```

I don't know what to do, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [policy-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) [routing](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html). Quick distro-agnostic example:

```
echo 200 custom >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 192.168.1.8 lookup custom
ip route add default via 10.76.8.50 dev eth0 table custom
```

Comment: http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html